# What is the spin of an operator in QFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, tensor-calculus, representation-theory

Operators in quantum field theory with $n$ Lorentz indices that are symmetrized and traceless are referred to as spin-$n$ operators. For example, a spin two operator would be
\begin{equation}
\bar{\psi}(\gamma^{\mu}\partial^{\nu}+\gamma^{\nu}\partial^{\mu})\psi-\bar{\psi}\gamma^{\mu}{\partial}_{\mu}\psi
\end{equation}
Where does this language come from and why?

Comment: You might get more answers if you posted an example where this language shows up? I have a vague idea but I can't double-check if it's right.